# Entity Framework not recognising existing objects

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm having the usual chasing my tail scenario with Entity Framework. My architecture is MVC website, C# WCF RESTful web service layer, Entity Framework code first DB layer.

I have a DbUserProfile object in the database. Each user chooses their preferences in a number of categories such as their diet, their ethnicity, their body type etc. These choices come from a pre-set list held in the database. Using Code-First, I designed an object hierachy so that the base class was called UserChoice and all the others inherit from that, eg DietChoice, EthnicityChoice, BodyTypeChoice. The parent class contains the only two properties, Id and Description. EF represents this by putting them all in the same table with a discriminator column.

I have represented my profile object by containing the actual User Choice objects that the user has selected, not just Ids. So the UserProfile class contains an actual DietChoice object, a BodyTypeChoice object etc.

In order to pass objects to my website UI layer, I convert all EF objects into model objects which are identical property-wise, just different object types to separate the layers and dependencies. So in the data layer it is a DbUserProfile, I then convert that to a UserProfile object which I then pass over WCF to the website. The user then makes changes to their profile, submits the updates and the UserProfile object gets sent back to the web service for update. The web service converts it back to a DbUserProfile object and tries to update it in the repository.

The problem I have is because of the conversion between EF and model objects, by the time it makes the round trip and gets converted back to Db object, EF thinks it is a new object and tries to insert as new. It doesnt seem to look at the Primary Key of the object, recognise that it already exists, and update it. In particular, there are about 15 choices the user makes as described above. I would want the data layer to understand these options already exist in the database, linked by the Id column. But if you select DietChoice with Id=1 and try to update the profile object, EF thinks it is a NEW DietChoice object, ignores the Id=1 and saves it in the UserChoice table at the end, with Id=142 for example.

This seems very messy and I'm sure I'm doing something bad with my design but can anyone point me back on the right track?

Comment: Sounds like a very good clean design. The obvious way would be implementing the logic in the service to a)call a SP that updates the entity (without using EF) or b) taking the Entity (from DB) and update it with the entity in your service and save it. A different solution could be modifiing the entities in the ObjectState Manager, but I won't recommend that. I'm looking forward for the answers cause I'm using EF too...

Comment: One interesting thing I've just stumbled upon while experimenting is if you use explicit foreign keys, this problem seems to go away. For example if you have Profile.Diet, Profile.Ethnicity etc which are the objects themselves, then add in DietId and EthnicityId parameters too which EF picks up by convention. When you re-map back to the EF DB objects, don't populate the Diet and Ethnicity objects, instead just populate the DietId and EthnicityId integer properties. This seems to work!